# DATABASECHANGELOG not generated by liquibase when I use it with scylladb

Tags: scala, sbt, liquibase, scylla

I'm new to liquibase and I want to use it on **scylladb database**, although it's a small project but instead of creating schema by hand I would like to use something more professional like liquibase.

What i did to achieve this task.

- Install **liquibase-4.1.1** onj my local machine.
- Created **three** nodes cluster of **scylladb** .
- Created **test01** keyspace in it.

I'm using **scala** language having **sbt.version = 1.2.8**

What I did in **scala** is given below.

- Created new scala project.
- Add dependency in build.sbt.
- Created a **liquibase-file** directory in which I created **liquibase.properties** file.
- Created **liquibase.sql** file in **src/main/resources**.
- Add the necessary drivers **CassandraJDBC42.jar** and **liquibase-cassandra-4.1.1.2.jar** as a library (goto **File/project Structure** then add the drivers and extensions from download folder)

build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "scylladb_liquibase"
  )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.liquibase" % "liquibase-core" % "4.1.1",
  "com.scylladb" % "java-driver-core" % "4.15.0.0",
  "org.ow2.util.bundles" % "cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5" % "1.0.0")
```

Scala object:

```
import liquibase.Liquibase
import liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor

import java.io.File
import java.sql.DriverManager

object Liquibase extends App {
  val props = new java.util.Properties()
  val fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(new File("liquibase-files/liquibase.properties"))
  props.load(fis)
  fis.close()

  val jdbcUrl = props.getProperty("url")
  val driver = props.getProperty("driver")
  Class.forName(driver)

  val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl)

  val jdbcConnection = new JdbcConnection(connection)

  // Run the Liquibase migration
  val liquibase = new Liquibase("changelog.sql", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), jdbcConnection)

  // Execute the SQL statement
  liquibase.update("")
}
```

liquibase.properties:

```
url= jdbc:cassandra://172.24.0.3:9042/test01;DefaultKeyspace=test01
driver= com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver
defaultSchemaName= test01
```

liquibase.sql

```sql
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset asif:1
CREATE TABLE test01.TESTME1 ( foo int PRIMARY KEY, bar text );
--rollback DROP TABLE test01.TESTME2;
--changeset asif:2
CREATE TABLE test01.TESTME2 ( foo int PRIMARY KEY, bar text );
--rollback DROP TABLE test01.TESTME2;
```

When I run(update) the program it generate an error

```
INFO: No DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK available in cassandra.
```

Through terminal I found that the **databasechangelog** not created but **databasechangeloglock** created.

What I tried:

- Update the table schema through the terminal using command **liquibase update** now it both **databasechangelog, databasechangeloglock** created successfully and update the schema as well (means working fine).
- Then I try it again with help of my scala code **It only execute the first changeset and then lock the databasechangelog remaining changesets does not executed**

Here is an error:

```
May 03, 2023 1:20:13 PM liquibase.logging
INFO: successfully.acquired.change.log.lock
May 03, 2023 1:20:13 PM liquibase.servicelocator
INFO: Cannot load service: liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParser: liquibase.parser.core.json.JsonChangeLogParser Unable to get public no-arg constructor
May 03, 2023 1:20:13 PM liquibase.servicelocator
INFO: Cannot load service: liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParser: liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser Unable to get public no-arg constructor
May 03, 2023 1:20:13 PM liquibase.ext
INFO: Creating database history table with name: "".DATABASECHANGELOG
May 03, 2023 1:20:13 PM liquibase.ext
INFO: Reading from "".DATABASECHANGELOG
May 03, 2023 1:20:14 PM liquibase.servicelocator
INFO: Cannot load service: liquibase.hub.HubService: Provider liquibase.hub.core.OnlineHubService could not be instantiated
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL UPDATE "".DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL WHERE ID = 1: [Simba][CassandraJDBCDriver](500211) ERROR Invalid query: UPDATE "".DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL WHERE ID = 1, Cause: com.simba.cassandra.shaded.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8  : missing elements...
.
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:95)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.update(JdbcExecutor.java:278)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.update(JdbcExecutor.java:246)
    at liquibase.ext.cassandra.lockservice.LockServiceCassandra.releaseLock(LockServiceCassandra.java:126)
```

We can release that lock from cqlsh using command:

```
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET locked=false, lockgranted=null, lockedby=null WHERE id=1;
```

But when I run program again, its behavior remain same as I described, **first changeset** works then it do not release lock.

What is the main issue, Where I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

We see an exception of missing elements. The problem is when we run this program, it executes first changeset and acquire lock - then it send entry to **databasechangelog** table. Now the problem is it is sending 13 values i.e.,

```
[Simba][CassandraJDBCDriver](500211) ERROR Invalid query: INSERT INTO "".DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('111', 'sheng.w', 'changelog.xml', 1683178609999, 3, '8:1dc9bb64b8fe1be5bf4a6ed2f1bb88ef', 'sql', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.1.1', '3178609878'), Cause: com.simba.cassandra.shaded.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:13  : missing elements...
```

It is not sending **'tag'** column's value. In **cqlsh** autogenerated table **databasechangelog** has 14 columns. For this problem I've searched on different browsers and found we can send **'tag'** via **xml** - so I created **'changelog.xml'** just to check what if we send **'tag'**.

**changelog.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-3.9.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.9.xsd">

    <changeSet id="111" author="zaryab">
        <tagDatabase tag="1.1" />
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Now it is sending **'tag'** but still exception is same.

```
[Simba][CassandraJDBCDriver](500211) ERROR Invalid query: INSERT INTO "".DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID, TAG) VALUES ('111', 'zaryab', 'changelog.xml', 1683178609999, 3, '8:1dc9bb64b8fe1be5bf4a6ed2f1bb88ef', 'tagDatabase', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.1.1', '3178609878', '1.1'), Cause: com.simba.cassandra.shaded.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:13  : missing elements...
```

Help us in that, how can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about scylladb or cassandra, but from looking at the supported databases page scylladb is not supported.  There must be enough of a behind the scenes difference between the 2 to prevent Liquibase from working.

https://www.liquibase.com/supported-databases?category=advanced,contributed,foundational